# Detect if mouse is Waiting or Busy using python

Tags: python, mouse-cursor

I am creating a script in Python 2.7. The script automates mouse clicks, within an application.

There are instances that after a  mouse click, the mouse cursor will be *"Waiting"*, I want to wait until the mouse cursor changes back to normal before I go to the next step within the code.

Is it possible within python to detect whether the mouse is waiting?

Comment: How are you automating your clicks? Are you using something like PyAutoGui?

Comment: @Chris I am using pynput